# Pyexcel, how to save a dict to csv file with pyexcel?

Tags: python, dictionary, save, xls, pyexcel

This part of the topic is solved, see my last answer to this topic.
I'm having trouble to save a dictionary using the pyexcel module.

I instaled the pyxecel module with `pip3 install pyexcel`

So I have a dictionary and I'm doing this:

```
import pyexcel as pe
myDict = {...}
pe.save_as(dict = myDict, dest_file_name = "dest_file.xls")
```

In my terminal, when I compile the code, it prints myDict but just after I have this:

```
Otherwise unrecognized parameters were given.
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuBZ8.png)

I look for a solution and it could be related to this: https://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html
But I don't understand how to use the --hiden-import in my code or terminal? When I use this in my code I have a syntax error.

Can someone help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

edit: use `pe.save_as(adict = myDict, dest_file_name = "dest_file.xls")` to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that pyinstaller is failing? You haven't included any information about how you are using pyinstaller.

Comment: I mean I instaled pyexcel with pip3 and that all.

Comment: So you typed `pip3 install pyexcel` and that produced the error in your post?

Comment: It is not returned as an error, but yeah no file is saved and I have this message: Otherwise unrecognized parameters were given.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to explain that your post does not include enough information to help you. See this on producing a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok I'm going to edit the original post so.

Comment: I add what I could to describe as precise as possible what my problem is.

Comment: That's helpful. In the future, please also include a minimal dict in case the issue would have been with your input data. The problem is that you are calling `pyexcel.save_as()` with the parameters "dict" and "dest_file_name". According to the docs, that function doesn't accept either of those params: http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.save_as.html#pyexcel-save-as

Comment: Sorry, correction for my last comment. It does accept `dest_file_name` but it doesn't accept a param called `dict`.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using the XLS file format?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is failing is because the method call `save_as()` doesn't accept a parameter named `dict`. According to the documentation, providing a dict should either be done via the `adict` or `with_keys` parameters:

```
pe.save_as(adict = myDict, dest_file_name = "dest_file.xls")
```