# Pyexcel, how to save into columns and how to disable to auto sort after saving?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, save, pyexcel

I'm trying to use the pyexcel module, but I just don't find any solution for my problem.

So I'm saving a dictionary to a csv file:

```
myDict = {'the' = '3.2', 'there' = '5.5',...}
sheet = pe.get_sheet(adict = myDict)
sheet.save_as("Word_Frequency_Stat.csv")
```

First I want the data to be ordered into 2 columns, words and values in my file and then I want to disable the auto-sort because my dictionary is already ordered by value.

If someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: _I want the data to be ordered into 2 columns_ What is the current format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyexcel, How to save a dictionary in column and unable the sort from pyexcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423084/pyexcel-how-to-save-a-dictionary-in-column-and-unable-the-sort-from-pyexcel)

Comment: The current format is 2 rows, on the first one words {the,  there...} And on the second values {3.3,  5.5...}.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it:

So basicaly, convert my dictionary to a list like this:

```
keys = []
values = []
for key, value in s_words.items():
    keys.append(key)
    values.append(value)
```

Then I used OrderedDict:

```
o_words = OrderedDict({'words': keys, 'frequency': values})
```

And when I save the file:

```
sheet = pe.get_sheet(adict = o_words)
sheet.save_as("Word_Frequency_Stat.csv")
```